# How to use Generic to create a feasible record variable in python?

Tags: python, generics

I want to achieve a class `Var` that can

- Inherit class `int` or `float` according to the type of the initialized parameter `init`

For example,

```
class Var:
    def __new__(cls, init=0.):
        super(Var, cls).__new__(init)

    def __init__(self, init=0.):
        super(Var, self).__init__()
```

When the type of `init` is `int`, class `Var` inherits `int`, and it works the same way with the type of `float`.

I guess `Generic` in python may help, but I don't know how.

---

**Update**

for now, my solution is:

```
def Var(init):
    fcls = type(init)
    class MyVar(fcls):
        def __new__(cls, init=0.):
            return super(MyVar, cls).__new__(cls, init)

        def __init__(self, init=0.):
            super(MyVar, self).__init__()
    return MyVar(init)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=Var(3.)   # 3.0
    b=Var(3)    # 3
    print(a, b) # 3.0 3
```

Comment: "Inherit class int or float according to the type of the initialized parameter init" don't, that isn't how inheritance is supposed to work and doesn't make sense. Instead, create both subclasses, then a function `def var(init)` that returns the appropriate instance based on the parameter `init`. `typing.Generic` is not for this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, sry, but I don't understand. What I want to achieve is a class template in python, and create an instance of it according to the type of `init`. Do you mean that python doesn't support this template?

Comment: I don't know precisely what you are referring to by "template". In any case, a single class should not dynamically inherit. Again, just create two classes, and create an appropriate instance based on the input, the "factory pattern".

Comment: If you mean C++ like templates, then *you dont' need that in Python*, that doesn't make sense in a dynamically typed language (although, for type annotations, which are a statically typed system, `typing.Generic` can be used, but there is no runtime necessity for that, that is a *type hint*),

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga tks, I update my solution and create a inner class dynamically

Comment: Don't do that. What's the point? Note, that creates *a whole new class object each time*. At least cache this. But really, just create two seperate classes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga，tks, I understand your concern. But I want to incorporate more types, like `list`, `set`, and I cannot explicitly create them all.